# How to do match multiple nested object in one document with inner hits in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-dsl, nested-object

How do I write a query with two search terms which matches nested objects with inner hits highlighted.

Below is the sample usecase:

I have a mapping:

```
"mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "grocery_name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "items": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "stock": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "category": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and the data looks like below

```
{
  "grocery_name": "Elastic Eats",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Red banana",
      "stock": "12",
      "category": "fruit"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cavendish banana",
      "stock": "10",
      "category": "fruit"
    },
    {
      "name": "peach",
      "stock": "10",
      "category": "fruit"
    },
    {
      "name": "carrot",
      "stock": "9",
      "category": "vegetable"
    },
    {
      "name": "broccoli",
      "stock": "5",
      "category": "vegetable"
    }
  ]
}
```

here if i want a document which has ***peach*** and ***carrot*** both in nested docs
i can do search with multiple nested queries like below

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "items",
            "query": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "items.name": {
                  "query": "carrot"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "items",
            "query": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "items.name": {
                  "query": "peach"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the above query works perfectly, but if i add inner hits i can't add for both nested queries , if i do i get following error

> [inner_hits] already contains an entry for key[items]

i want to get each matched nested object highlighted, as **_source** highlighting is not supported in elasticsearch is there any way i can do highlighting for each nested object?

Answer (score 5):

You certainly can have multiple `inner_hits` but they need to be appropriately **named**:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "inner_hits": {
              "name": "carrot"     <--
            }, 
            "path": "items",
            "query": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "items.name": {
                  "query": "carrot"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "inner_hits": {     
              "name": "peach"      <--
            },
            "path": "items",
            "query": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "items.name": {
                  "query": "peach"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You were getting the error b/c if no name is provided, the system will default to the nested path which is `items` in both of your subqueries.

Comment: I completely agree with your answer but in my case i can have multiple nested objects and i'm constructing  this DSL dynamically parsing from lucene query language is there any easy way to highlight each nested match instead of doing multiple inner hits, something like  `_source` highlighting.

Comment: Not with nested fields, no. AFAIK named inner hits are the only way to go.

Comment: I cannot tell you how much this answer helped me! I thought the "path" was what had to be unique, so I created all this logic (as my queries were being built dynamically) to combine terms into a single nested query and all I had to do to keep them separate was remove inner hits or give it a name. Geez! Thank you, thank you thank you!